# How to source only selected lines from a key=value formatted file?

Tags: linux, bash

I like to export only `NAME` and `YEAR` from ab.txt shown below
Below solution works, but there should be a way to do without creating second file `b.txt` ?
Please note there could be spaces in the `value`.

```
$ cat /tmp/ab.txt
TYPE=Sedan
NAME=VolksWagen golf
YEAR=2014
CITY=NY
OWNERS=3
CONDITION=Fair
$ grep "NAME=\|YEAR=" /tmp/ab.txt > /tmp/b.txt
$ source <(sed 's/=/="/; s/ *$/"/' /tmp/b.txt)
$ echo $NAME
VolksWagen golf
$ echo $YEAR
2014
$ echo $OWNERS

$
```

Comment: it didn't escape `"` with `NAME=VolksWagen" golf`

Comment: Naturally it didn't. You didn't mention anything about that on your question. And you said in the comments _"@Philippe, in my case, value will **not have** a " "_.

Comment: yes @accdias, I don't need that, what you provided works, thanks again.

Comment: Sorry, I don't want to challenge accdias' solution, just want to find a general solution. Particularly one which does not use `source`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You already have the answer on your own question. You just need to combine the pieces:

```sh
source <(egrep 'NAME=|YEAR=' /tmp/ab.txt | sed 's/=/="/; s/ *$/"/')
```

Or:

```
source <(awk -F= '/NAME=|YEAR=/{print $1 "=" "\"" $2 "\""}' /tmp/ab.txt)
```

And one last alternative:

```
source <(awk -F= '/NAME=|YEAR=/{printf "%s=\"%s\"\n",$1,$2}' /tmp/ab.txt)
```

I hope it helps.